# Regex function causing chrome to hang

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to find specific words in an html page to replace, however when I run it the RegExp() function is causing chrome to hang. The code below is the section where this is happening

```
function test(findWord, replaceWord){
    var searchregexp = new RegExp(findWord.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'), "gi");
    console.log(searchregexp);
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
            var node = element.childNodes[j];
            if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                var text = node.nodeValue;
                var replacedText = text.replace(searchregexp, replaceWord);
                if (replacedText !== text) {
                    element.innerHTML = replacedText;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Based on some other things I've read it seems to be that the RegExp function is causing catastrophic backtracking, but I am not really sure why that's the case or how I would solve it.

The code works if I hardcode a specific regular expression like /replace/gi into text.replace(). However, if I try to make it so that the word being replaced doesn't have to be constant and using the new RegExp function chrome hangs

Comment: You code works but stops as soon as there is a word outside a tag: `<div>Bla</div>
    <span>bla</span>bla will stop this
    <div>Bla</div>` using `test("bla","hello")`

Comment: Interesting, do you know how to deal with this? Also, it seems to hang no matter what word I choose to find but I imagine not all the words I search are outside a tag

Comment: Try with a recursive function like `hiliteWords` found in [this repo](https://github.com/GerHobbelt/hilitor/blob/master/hilitor.js)

Comment: There's a bug in your code; it assigns to element.innerHTML. The fix is to assign to node.nodeValue. BTW you can probably find the text nodes faster using TreeWalker API.